# How to copy the conditional formatting without copying the rules from a Conditional Formatted cell?

Tags: excel

I have a row of data with conditional formatting in it.

I need to copy this row to another row. This new row must be identical (values, formats), but static, i.e. without the rules. If I copy and paste the row and clear the rules, the formatting from the CF rule vanishes.

Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried? You can just do Conditional Formatting>Clear Rules>From Selected Cells. Do you need more than that? Are you looking for a VBA solution?

Comment: @DougGlancy I need to keep the formatting on the new line. If I clear the rules the format vanishes.

Comment: Clearing Conditional Formatting doesn't clear other formatting.

Comment: @DougGlancy I need to keep the formatting from the CF rule, without the rule.

Comment: Ohhh. Good luck :)! Let us know if you figure it out. If the formatting is simple enough, e.g., color a cell, you can do it with VBA.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just discovered an easy way: **Copy the table to MS Word and copy it back to excel :D**

---

It worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Note that if you copy disjoint cells, say some from column C and some from column G, and then paste in Excel, you'll get just the selected cells, in two adjoining columns.  If you instead paste into Word (or other apps), you'll get the cells from columns D, E and F as well, which is probably not what you want.  There doesn't seem to be a way around that, other than cleaning up the table after pasting.

Comment: This used to work great, but for some reason this only works for me now if I saved the copied table as a new Word document, close Word, then re-open Word and paste back into Excel.

Comment: Where were you like 2 hours ago?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using the "Office Clipboard" Pane ...

Copy the formatted region, then go to the "paste" page and open the Office Clipboard Pane, it is the small button in the right lower corner here:
[Office Clipboard pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmGaS.png)

Then click on the "copied" content and it will paste it with formats and without conditional formatting. Very hidden, and not intuitive at all

[Source](https://www.bookkempt.com/2017/08/remove-conditional-formatting-but-keep.html)

Answer (score 2):

I found a dead easy solution to this problem.

1. Copy the cells with the results of conditional formatting that you want to duplicate in another place.
2. Paste into an OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet (I used build 4.1.5) as Formatted - RTF. The formatting is still there, but OpenOffice apparently discards the conditions that created the formatting in the first place.
3. Now simply copy and paste into Excel.
4. Crack open the champagne.

This works with Excel files thousands of lines long.

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste to Google Sheets, then copy and paste back into Excel.

(I had to resort to this because the copy/paste to Word didn't work for me)

Answer (score 0):

First copy then look for "paste all" option. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel copy / Word paste/ copy/ Excel paste again is the only quick way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution for this! Once you have added your conditional formatting, simply add Filtering to your table, then click the filter (down arrow) on any of the Header columns > click Filter by Color > choose color > select all > choose same background color as background > Remove Filtering.  Then you will go back to Conditional Formatting, remove the rule and you will still have the colors on the cells that the conditional formatting did, just without all of the extra load of actually having the Conditional Formatting rule set.  I hope that helps and isn't too confusing. I forgot to mention that this specific example was related to background colors, but you can also filter on text colors as well.

Answer (score -3):

1. Press `CTRL+C` on the cell(s) you want to copy.
2. Press `ALT > E > S > U` on the cell(s) you want the value(s) to be pasted.

The value(s) and the formatting will be pasted, but not the conditional formatting rule(s).

Comment: 1. Right Click on the cell(s) you want to copy. Click on Copy (or the equivalent in your language). 2. Right click on the cell(s) you want the values to be pasted on. Then, select "Paste Special" (or the equivalent in your language) and select the "Values and number formats" (or the equivalent in your language) radio button and click the "OK" button. That should work.